# SWIG void * parameters

Tags: python, c, swig

I have two structs (from a third party lib actually) in my swig .i file that follow this form:

```
typedef struct MY_STRUCT {
  void*       pParameter;
  unsigned long pLen;
} MY_STRUCT;
%extend MY_STRUCT
{
    MY_STRUCT()
    {
        MY_STRUCT *m= new MY_STRUCT();
        m->pParameter = NULL;
        m->pLen = 0;
        return m;
    }
}

typedef struct ANOTHER_STRUCT {
    char * another;
    unsigned long len;
} ANOTHER_STRUCT;
%extend ANOTHER_STRUCT
{
    ANOTHER_STRUCT()
    {
        ANOTHER_STRUCT *p= new ANOTHER_STRUCT();
        p->another = NULL;
        p->len = 0;
        return p;
    }
    unsigned long __len__()
    {
        return sizeof(ANOTHER_STRUCT);
    }
}
```

The pParameter in MY_STRUCT is a void * because it can be a char * or a pointer to a struct (such as ANOTHER_STRUCT). Handling just the char * mapping is simple using `%typemap(in) void* = char*;`, but any attempt to use a struct fails. Here's what I'd like to see in Python:

```
s = MY_STRUCT()
another = ANOTHER_STRUCT()
s.pParameter = another # this should pass the struct pointer
s.pParameter = "some string" # or a char pointer if this is provided
```

Is this possible? If not, do I need to declare some helper functions to assign the pointer values?

Comment: Given you used the `new` keyword I'm slightly confused why you need to use `%extend` for constructors, but that's besides the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with SWIG. You'll end up writing a [fairly large `if`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092786/python-c-api-switch-on-pyobject-type) to pick how to handle the Python input though, depending on how many types you want to handle. Here's a complete example of the two typemaps you'll need:

```
%module test

%typemap(in) void* pParameter (int res=0, void *other_struct=NULL) %{
  int len;
  res = SWIG_ConvertPtr($input, &other_struct, $descriptor(struct ANOTHER_STRUCT*), 0);
  if (SWIG_IsOK(res)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "struct\n");
    $1 = reinterpret_cast< ANOTHER_STRUCT * >(argp1);
    len = sizeof(ANOTHER_STRUCT);
  }
  else if (PyString_Check($input)) {
    $1 = PyString_AsString($input);
    len = strlen((const char*)$1);
    fprintf(stderr, "string\n");
  }
  //else if (...) {
  //}
  else {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_TypeError, "some more details, see special typemap variables docs for ideas");
  }
%}

%typemap(memberin) void* pParameter %{
  $1 = $input; //fobar $self
  $self->pLen = len;
%}

%inline %{
typedef struct MY_STRUCT {
  void*       pParameter;
  unsigned long pLen;
} MY_STRUCT;

typedef struct ANOTHER_STRUCT {
} ANOTHER_STRUCT;
%}

%extend MY_STRUCT
{
    MY_STRUCT()
    {
        MY_STRUCT *m= new MY_STRUCT;
        m->pParameter = NULL;
        m->pLen = 0;
        return m;
    }
}
```

Here the `in` typemap takes a PyObject and figures out what to do with it. It also saves the length into a local variable.

The `memberin` typemap uses that to set the `void*` and the length as well appropriately.

You might want to consider making `pLen` immutable (see: `%immutable`) so that people can't arbitrarily change that pointer. You'll also need to consider the memory ownership semantics of a typemap like this carefully in order to avoid leaks or double frees.

Comment: Thanks flexo, I will check this out ASAP.